# What is the difference between the estimation technique used for `ARIMA()` and for `lm()` in R?

Tags: r, arima, lm

Does anyone have an idea on this?

In R, for `arima()`, I do the following:

```
arima(ts.GDP, order = c(3,0,0), seasonal = c(0,0,0))
```

and it provides the following output:

```
Call:
arima(x = ts.GDP, order = c(3, 0, 0), seasonal = c(0, 0, 0))

Coefficients:
         ar1     ar2     ar3  intercept
      0.2407  0.1436  0.2629     0.0124
s.e.  0.0869  0.0909  0.0898     0.0020

sigma^2 estimated as 6.735e-05:  log likelihood = 415.97,  aic = -821.95
```

Then, I do the following which in my view *should* be equivalent:

```
model_ts.GDP_1_small <- lm(ts.GDP[4:123] ~ ts.GDP[3:122] + ts.GDP[2:121] + ts.GDP[1:120])
```

And I get the following output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = ts.GDP[4:123] ~ ts.GDP[3:122] + ts.GDP[2:121] + 
    ts.GDP[1:120], method = "ML")

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-0.0222146 -0.0047417 -0.0002934  0.0050771  0.0172825 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   0.004835   0.001494   3.236  0.00158 **
ts.GDP[3:122] 0.190071   0.089678   2.119  0.03618 * 
ts.GDP[2:121] 0.122795   0.088298   1.391  0.16698   
ts.GDP[1:120] 0.248925   0.086214   2.887  0.00464 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.008091 on 116 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1905,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1695 
F-statistic: 9.097 on 3 and 116 DF,  p-value: 1.86e-05
```

But you can see that the coefficient estimates for the lags and also the constant are different for `ARIMA()` and the `lm()`. Why is this? Under what circumstances, conditions, etc. would they be equal?

Thanks!

The data I am using is the following:

```
              Qtr1          Qtr2          Qtr3          Qtr4
1987                0.0306561072  0.0392864507  0.0210152208
1988  0.0291329741  0.0210355622  0.0338417046  0.0331949628
1989  0.0207966312  0.0177082081  0.0275253025  0.0220798615
1990  0.0194239018  0.0272052229  0.0186120604  0.0028645884
1991  0.0177981849  0.0118575852  0.0090382534  0.0143525784
1992  0.0086642218  0.0021447137  0.0026138616  0.0163272277
1993  0.0234751810  0.0024896081  0.0178990561  0.0121073032
1994  0.0148942656  0.0087541767  0.0111651283  0.0206747221
1995  0.0038553216  0.0123077148  0.0181891502  0.0122825995
1996  0.0190786549  0.0208705336  0.0130352539  0.0096704741
1997  0.0102231595  0.0108006499  0.0278331806 -0.0082180178
1998  0.0140763378  0.0096570063  0.0096372708  0.0278646252
1999  0.0059741144 -0.0065275558  0.0128073593  0.0158744479
2000  0.0229761650  0.0135909394  0.0082163591  0.0037759459
2001  0.0086377916  0.0178515910  0.0031874057  0.0087325755
2002  0.0124498944  0.0123923278  0.0150171021  0.0174042006
2003  0.0143298994  0.0087005272  0.0151287750  0.0181491241
2004  0.0077652238  0.0165165045  0.0038926175  0.0088177118
2005  0.0136287038  0.0254171510  0.0095686519  0.0234991732
2006  0.0100988453  0.0100253125  0.0109846241  0.0093825128
2007  0.0155345001  0.0099758281  0.0179426970  0.0126651309
2008  0.0140290574 -0.0049239526 -0.0061866988 -0.0142049076
2009 -0.0160537386 -0.0010636061  0.0078445461  0.0024718497
2010  0.0121380410  0.0154901054  0.0016324070  0.0082145339
2011  0.0245406708 -0.0057541446  0.0036017420  0.0099174607
2012  0.0075758940  0.0014265201  0.0251534789  0.0030763272
2013  0.0067666626  0.0076338005  0.0182574142  0.0075309951
2014  0.0137049222  0.0148989339  0.0087182023  0.0005507058
2015  0.0049534523  0.0168360432  0.0006563102  0.0046847140
2016  0.0156830127  0.0085513744  0.0086166046  0.0145653945
2017  0.0100121096  0.0043618850  0.0052574221  0.0089575028
```

Comment: Did you look at the help for arima?  It explains how it estimates the parameters, and it’s not via OLS.

Comment: @TheLaconic I did for both. I thought ARIMA was estimated via MLE? (As is `ml()`, no?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help:

> fitting method: maximum likelihood or minimize conditional sum-of-squares. The default (unless there are missing values) is to use conditional-sum-of-squares to find starting values, then maximum likelihood...
>
> The exact likelihood is computed via a state-space representation of the ARIMA process, and the innovations and their variance found by a Kalman filter.

The difference from lm, where you just drop the observations for which the required lagged values are unknown and use OLS (which will give you the same point estimates as using MLE), is that arima *doesn't* drop the first few observations.  The lagged values of the dependent variable are state variables in the state-space representation, for which the Kalman filter will (given some values for the parameters to be estimated) compute estimated distributions in the periods where they are unknown.  The arima function is therefore able to squeeze a bit of extra information out of the observations that are dropped (explicitly or automatically) by the lm function.

I can't think of any conditions under which the two methods would give the same answer, except by accident, and of course in the $T \rightarrow \infty$ limit.